# Why do I get a 'bad data' error in glmer?

Tags: r, lme4, lmertest

I want to remove outliers (with residuals beyond 2.5sd) from my model. I have tried this code:

```
acc.glmer1=glmer(correct_answer ~ condition + (1|Participant) + (1|word), 
data = ldt[abs(scale(resid(acc.glmer)))<2.5,], family="binomial")
```

and I get the following error message:

> Error: bad 'data':

I run the same code on a different dataset and it runs smoothly without any issues.

Comment: What happens if you do `mydata <- ldt[abs(scale(resid(acc.glmer)))<2.5,]` and then use `mydata` in the call to glmer() ?

Comment: Could we have a [mcve] please ... ? (Is that the full error message?)